# Как сделать выполнение функции php через form?

Tags: php

Есть класс с функцией добавления данных о пользователе в БД.Сделал форму,хотелось бы чтобы при заполнении формы и нажатии кнопки submit выполнялась функция класса сразу в этой же странице.Как это сделать?
http://pastebin.com/TghqpuPH вот код формы,если надо могу добавить код класса.
Заранее спасибО!

Comment: Добавьте в input = "submit" - name = "submit", а вот это вставьте перед формой в этом файле:

    if (!empty($_POST['submit'])){
    // тут проверьте все поля (условиями)
    // теперь создайте экземпляр класса, и вызывайте методы 
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас непонимание либо процесса работы PHP либо процесса работы html и форм в частности.
Возможно вы имеете ввиду делать запрос без перезагрузки страницы, в этом случае вам поможет jquery ajax.